# Lost references in Visual Studio 2017 solution

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, reference, visual-studio-2017

I've been working on a project with a coworker and we're using Visual Studio 2017 as IDE and also Git to push the versions to VS repository. We had a few problems and decided to start a new project in Visual Studio with the content we already had.

The weird thing is: when cloned the repository to my computer and synched, some of the references were lost. A yellow triangle appears next to the lost references icons in Solution Explorer, and it doesn't have a path set like the ones that work. Also, inside Source > Repos, the project folder has all files, including the ones that are missing. I tried deleting the project and cloning it again, tried to download only the .zip file and starting the project offline, and also running VS 2017 as administrator (it appears this solved similar problems for others before) and nothing worked. My coworker (who pushed the project to the repo in first place) can compile normally and is not facing this reference problem.

Has anyone ever experienced this issue?

Comment: so many things can go wrong here. Are packages restored? have all the required solution files been checked into to the repository?

Comment: All the required files are in the repository. The ones that are missing have even been cloned to my local repository, I just can't acess them... What do you mean by packages being restored?

Comment: Packages as in NuGet packages. Run `dotnet restore` in the project folder.

Comment: Sorry, it took a while to run the command. It displayed "Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're using VSTS with a git repository, and this happens all the time, especially when pulling updated solutions. I find a clean and rebuild fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can run in the Package Manager Console the following command to clean up the nugget packages:

```
Update-Package -reinstall -ProjectName XYZProjectName
```

or run it for the whole solution:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case after a merge with the master branch, I had conflicts in the project file (.csproj). When resolving the issue VS2019 automatically had unloaded the project file where those conflicts were and I didn't notice. A check for that might save time for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I once experienced it when I was having a Visual Studio 2015 project open and then pulling new git commits. The new project I was pulling was was set up for Visual Studio 2017 though.

So my VS 2015 was open and dsiplaying the now VS 2017 project. I believe it only contained one nuget package, however this was not downloaded correctly and instead the package was displayed as a missing file.

Maybe this is happening for you too?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem in VSC 2021 version 1.63.
Solution - Removed  project folder from workspace:
CTRL+Shift+P, search for and execute the
"Workspace: Remove Folder from Workspace" command.
Then reopened the project folder and was OK